# Grab row of dataframe based max value across two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is dataframe 1

```
  card  value  cat1  cat2  cat3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        10     1     2     3
2 A        20     4     5     6
3 B        30     7     8     9
4 A        40    10    11    12
```

Here is dataframe 2 with the same number of rows and columns

```
  card  value  cat1  cat2  cat3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 C        11    13    14    15
2 C        19    16    17    18
3 A        35    19    20    21
4 B        45    22    23    24
```

I want to create a new dataframe that is chosen based on the maximum value of the "value" column. The row of the new dataframe is the entire row of the dataframe that has the highest number in the "value" column.

Thus the desired solution is:

```
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 C        11    13    14    15
2 A        20     4     5     6
3 A        35    19    20    21
4 B        45    22    23    24
```

These are demo dataframes. The actual data frames are on the order of 200,000 rows. What is the best way to do this? Note, it would also be good to have a column in the new dataframe indicating which data frame the row was from: df_1 or df_2.

Dataframes

```
df_1 <- structure(list(card = c("A", "A", "B", "A"), value = c(10, 20, 
30, 40), cat1 = c(1, 4, 7, 10), cat2 = c(2, 5, 8, 11), cat3 = c(3, 
6, 9, 12)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df_2 <- structure(list(card = c("C", "C", "A", "B"), value = c(11, 19, 
35, 45), cat1 = c(13, 16, 19, 22), cat2 = c(14, 17, 20, 23), 
    cat3 = c(15, 18, 21, 24)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I don't have a full answer, however `pmax(df_1$value, df_2$value)`  will find the parallel max and might be a step on your journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably avoid needing to do this as a grouped operation if you stack each dataset and offset the row indexes. E.g.:

```
sel <- max.col(cbind(df_1$value, df_2$value))
rbind(df_1, df_2)[seq_along(sel) + c(0,nrow(df_1))[sel],]

## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  card  value  cat1  cat2  cat3
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 C        11    13    14    15
#2 A        20     4     5     6
#3 A        35    19    20    21
#4 B        45    22    23    24
```

`sel` will contain the source dataset too.

```
cbind(rbind(df_1, df_2)[seq_along(sel) + c(0,nrow(df_1))[sel],], src=sel)

#  card value cat1 cat2 cat3 src
#1    C    11   13   14   15   2
#2    A    20    4    5    6   1
#3    A    35   19   20   21   2
#4    B    45   22   23   24   2
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `base` solutions

1. `ifelse`

```r
do.call(rbind,
  ifelse(df1$value >= df2$value,
         split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)),
         split(df2, 1:nrow(df2)))
)
```

2. `lapply`

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), \(x) {
  if(df1$value[x] >= df2$value[x]) df1[x, ] else df2[x, ]
}))

#   card value cat1 cat2 cat3
# 1    C    11   13   14   15
# 2    A    20    4    5    6
# 3    A    35   19   20   21
# 4    B    45   22   23   24
```

Comment: I tried an ifelse solution and could only returned one column at a time: `ifelse(df_1$value>=df_2$value, df_1[[1]], df_2[[1]])`. What is this magic `split()`!?